# referencing properties of subclasses

Tags: arduino, abstract-class

Given this Arduino C++ code which compiles without errors or warnings:

in Classes.h:

```
class TopClass {
private:
    int topValue;
public:
    TopClass(int v) : topValue(v) {};
    int getTop();
    virtual int getMiddle() = 0;
    virtual int getBottom() = 0;
};

class MiddleClass : public TopClass {
private:
    int middleValue;
public:
    MiddleClass(int v) : middleValue(v), TopClass(v * v) {};
    virtual int getMiddle();
};

class BottomClass : public MiddleClass {
private:
    int bottomValue;
public:
    BottomClass(int v) : bottomValue(v), MiddleClass(v * v) {};
    int getBottom();
};
```

In Classes.cpp:

```
int TopClass::getTop() {
    return topValue;
}
int MiddleClass::getMiddle() {
    return middleValue;
}
int BottomClass::getBottom() {
    return bottomValue;
}
```

In main;

```
BottomClass bottom1(2);
show(&bottom1);
BottomClass bottom2(3);
show(&bottom2);

void show(BottomClass *b) {
    Serial.print("bottom:"); Serial.println(b->getBottom());
    Serial.print("middle:"); Serial.println(b->getMiddle());
    Serial.print("top:"); Serial.println(b->getTop());
}
```

The above code works but does not solve my problem.

Assume that I add:

```
DifferentBottomClass : public MiddleClass {
private:
    int bottomValue;
public:
    DifferentBottomClass(int v) : bottomValue(v), MiddleClass(v * v) {};
    int getBottom();
};

int DifferentBottomClass::getBottom() {
    return bottomValue;
}
```

Now the show function stops working because it was based on a BottomClass, not DifferentBottomClass.

What I need is the ability to slide in as many different versions of BottomClass as I want without having to change any of the parent code or the show function.

If I add:

```
TopClass *top;
top->getTop();
top->getMiddle();
top->getBottom();
```

All compile, but because *top is pointing nowhere, the code blows up.

How do I initialize *top so that it finds the currently instantiated version of each subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should be:

```
class TopClass {
public:
    int topValue = 1;
    int getTop();
    virtual int getMiddle() = 0;
    virtual int getBottom() = 0;
};

class MiddleClass : public TopClass
{
public:
    int middleValue = 2;
    virtual int getMiddle();
};

class BottomClass : public MiddleClass
{
public:
    int bottomValue = 3;
    int getBottom();

};

int TopClass::getTop() {
    return topValue;
}
int MiddleClass::getMiddle() {
    return middleValue;
}
int BottomClass::getBottom() {
    return bottomValue;
}
```

The problem is that you had a recursive call on to itself when you call getTop(), getMiddle() and getBottom(). If it was a desktop application, it probably would have given you a stack overflow exception before crashing.

Comment: This cannot work because TopClass is abstract and TopClass *top creates an uninitialized pointer. This is why the code is crashing. See my revised code edits